# How to fill Query Build Data Sources (qbds) value with Table Field

Tags: axapta, x++

I'm a newbie programmer on Microsoft dynamics AX

Can I use this Source Code :

```
qbds.addRange(fieldNum(Table1,AccountNum)).value(queryValue(fieldNum(Table2, AccountNum)));
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Part for `addRange` is ok. For `value` you have to use exact value (`.value(queryValue(Table2.AccountNum))`).

Answer (score 1):

As Matej mentioned you will have to do:

```
qbds.addRange(fieldNum(Table1,AccountNum)).value(queryValue(table2.AccountNum));
```

This provided you have the `table2` buffer available.

If `Table2` is in the query, use [addLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/querybuilddatasource.addlink.aspx) instead:

```
qbds.addLink(fieldNum(Table2,AccountNum), fieldNum(Table1,AccountNum));
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what result are you expecting. If you run your code, you'll get next range:

`table1.Account num = 65500` for  example, because `fieldnum()` function returns field ID.

If you want to filter `AccountNum` from `table1`, you just need to add

```
qbds.addRange(fieldnum(table1,  accountNum)).value(queryRange(table2.accountnum)));
```

and you'll get right range.

Adding range by `fieldNum` value to field is need for some system actions or when you have `fieldnum` value in your table for some reasons. I rarely see this one.